# How to access GameObject via interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public interface IAimPanel
{
    public GameObject GetGameObject();
}


public class Target : MonoBehaviour, IAimPanel
{
    public GameObject GetGameObject()
    {
        return gameObject;
    }
}


public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IAimPanel aimPanel;

    private void Start()
    {
        aimPanel.GetGameObject().SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access gameObject via interface in Unity C#, I've done it in the code above, but I want a more elegant implementation.

Something like this

```
private void Start()
{
    aimPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method into a property in the class and interface.

```
public interface IAimPanel
{
    GameObject GameObject { get; }
}

public class Target : MonoBehaviour, IAimPanel
{
    public GameObject GameObject => gameObject;
}
```

And then you'll be able to access it the way you specified:

```
private void Start()
{
    aimPanel.GameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Note that the convention is that properties are capitalized, so that's why I used the name `GameObject` instead of `gameObject` for the property.

Comment: The `public` modifier is not valid for the interaface members, as they`re all public :)

Comment: apart from the properties capitalized convention (which I don't like), the inherited `gameObject` from the `Target` component would be hidden in case of low-case gameObject property, so any other name makes very much sense

Comment: @rustyBucketBay thanks for pointing this out, I tested with the `public` modifier in a .NET5 C#9 app and was able to compile, but in the case of the lower versions you're right it'll fail, so I edited my answer, thanks!